# querying for timestamp field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In my views i have the date in the following format `s_date=20090106` and `e_date=20100106`

The model is defined as

```
     class Activity(models.Model):
          timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

how to query for the timestamp filed with the above info.

```
   Activity.objects.filter(timestamp>=s_date and timestamp<=e_date)
```

Thanks.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to convert your date to an instance of `datetime.datetime` class. Easiest way to do it for your case is:

```
import datetime

#
# This creates new instace of `datetime.datetime` from a string according to
# the pattern given as the second argument.
#
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(s_date, '%Y%m%d')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(e_date, '%Y%m%d')

# And now the query you want. Mind that you cannot use 'and' keyword
# inside .filter() function. Fortunately .filter() automatically ANDs
# all criteria you provide.
Activity.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=start, timestamp__lte=end)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: No. You can't do filters with >= and <=. Filter arguments are keywords, not expressions. -1.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
s_date = datetime.strptime('20090106', '%Y%m%d')
e_date = datetime.strptime('20100106', '%Y%m%d')
Activity.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=s_date, timestamp__lte=e_date)
```

Note that first you need to use `strptime` to convert your string date to a python `datetime` object.  Second, you need to use the `gte` and `lte` methods to form a django query.